# JPA Criteria api Mulitple join with orderby

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Trying to write a criteria api query.

`cardholder id` is suppose to be passed as a parameter and can change. I have added the entities that i have in my code.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
select tx.id,tx.date,tx.settled,tx.settledDate,te.debit,te.amount,te.account,tx.card, acc.accountType, pl.name,mer.id, mer.name , ch.id 
from cardholder ch
join txn_entry te on ch.id=te.cardholder
join txn tx on te.txn = tx.id
join merchant mer on tx.merchant=mer.id
join account acc on te.account = acc.id
join plan pl on acc.plan= pl.id 
where te.cardholder= ? and tx.retcode = 00 and te.valid='Y'
order by tx.date desc;
```

THis is what i Have so far:

```
    public List<CardHolderEntity> createCriteriaQuery(String cardHolderId) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    char valid = 'Y';
    String returnCode = "00";
    CriteriaQuery<CardHolderEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(CardHolderEntity.class);

    Root<CardHolderEntity> cardHolder = cq.from(CardHolderEntity.class);

    Join<CardHolderEntity, TransactionEntryEntity> transactionEntries = cardHolder
            .join(CardHolderEntity_.transactionEntryEntity);
    Join<TransactionEntryEntity, AccountEntity> account = transactionEntries
            .join(TransactionEntryEntity_.accountEntity);
    Join<AccountEntity, PlanEntity> plans = account.join(AccountEntity_.planEntity);
    Join<TransactionEntryEntity, TransactionEntity> transaction = transactionEntries
            .join(TransactionEntryEntity_.transactionEntity);
    Join<TransactionEntity, CardEntity> cards = transaction.join(TransactionEntity_.cardEntity);
    Join<TransactionEntity, MerchantEntity> merchants = transaction.join(TransactionEntity_.merchantEntity);

    Predicate p1 = cb.equal(cardHolder.get(CardHolderEntity_.id), cardHolderId);
    Predicate p2 = cb.equal(transactionEntries.get(TransactionEntryEntity_.valid), valid);
    Predicate p3 = cb.equal(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.retcode), returnCode);

    cq.select(cardHolder).where(cb.and(p1, p2, p3))
            .orderBy(cb.desc(transactionEntries.get(TransactionEntryEntity_.id)));
    TypedQuery<CardHolderEntity> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    return qry.getSingleResult();
}
```

I am able to fetch the correct data now but the list is not ordered. This is what i see in my logs and there are two queries getting generated one has the order and the other doesnot.

```
Hibernate: select cardholder0_.id as id1_2_, cardholder0_.email as email2_2_, cardholder0_.firstname as firstnam3_2_, cardholder0_.issuer as issuer6_2_, cardholder0_.lastname as lastname4_2_, cardholder0_.phone as phone5_2_ from cardholder cardholder0_ inner join txn_entry transactio1_ on cardholder0_.id=transactio1_.cardholder inner join account accountent2_ on transactio1_.account=accountent2_.id inner join plan planentity3_ on accountent2_.plan=planentity3_.id inner join txn transactio4_ on transactio1_.txn=transactio4_.id inner join card cardentity5_ on transactio4_.card=cardentity5_.id inner join merchant merchanten6_ on transactio4_.merchant=merchanten6_.id where cardholder0_.id=? and transactio1_.valid=? and transactio4_.retcode=? order by transactio1_.id desc

Hibernate: select transactio0_.cardholder as cardhold6_2_6_, transactio0_.id as id1_8_6_, transactio0_.id as id1_8_5_, transactio0_.account as account5_8_5_, transactio0_.amount as amount2_8_5_, transactio0_.cardholder as cardhold6_8_5_, transactio0_.debit as debit3_8_5_, transactio0_.txn as txn7_8_5_, transactio0_.valid as valid4_8_5_, accountent1_.id as id1_0_0_, accountent1_.accounttype as accountt2_0_0_, accountent1_.active as active3_0_0_, accountent1_.enddate as enddate4_0_0_, accountent1_.plan as plan5_0_0_, planentity2_.id as id1_6_1_, planentity2_.onlineaccess as onlineac2_6_1_, planentity2_.enddate as enddate3_6_1_, planentity2_.name as name4_6_1_, transactio3_.id as id1_7_2_, transactio3_.card as card6_7_2_, transactio3_.date as date2_7_2_, transactio3_.merchant as merchant7_7_2_, transactio3_.retcode as retcode3_7_2_, transactio3_.settled as settled4_7_2_, transactio3_.settleddate as settledd5_7_2_, cardentity4_.id as id1_1_3_, cardentity4_.active as active2_1_3_, cardentity4_.cardholder as cardhold8_1_3_, cardentity4_.number as number3_1_3_, cardentity4_.createddate as createdd4_1_3_, cardentity4_.enddate as enddate5_1_3_, cardentity4_.issueddate as issuedda6_1_3_, cardentity4_.startdate as startdat7_1_3_, merchanten5_.id as id1_5_4_, merchanten5_.name as name2_5_4_ from txn_entry transactio0_ left outer join account accountent1_ on transactio0_.account=accountent1_.id left outer join plan planentity2_ on accountent1_.plan=planentity2_.id left outer join txn transactio3_ on transactio0_.txn=transactio3_.id left outer join card cardentity4_ on transactio3_.card=cardentity4_.id left outer join merchant merchanten5_ on transactio3_.merchant=merchanten5_.id where transactio0_.cardholder in (select cardholder0_.id from cardholder cardholder0_ inner join txn_entry transactio1_ on cardholder0_.id=transactio1_.cardholder inner join account accountent2_ on transactio1_.account=accountent2_.id inner join plan planentity3_ on accountent2_.plan=planentity3_.id inner join txn transactio4_ on transactio1_.txn=transactio4_.id inner join card cardentity5_ on transactio4_.card=cardentity5_.id inner join merchant merchanten6_ on transactio4_.merchant=merchanten6_.id where cardholder0_.id=? and transactio1_.valid=? and transactio4_.retcode=? )
```

Comment: similar situation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082972/order-by-in-criteria-api-for-a-computed-column-name-by-alias
Any idea how order by an alias name with JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing rather than going through cardHolder table i went through TransactionEntry and i was able to order the list. I still did not find anything where i was able to order it when i was going through to cardholder table. Hope this helps somebody.

```
  public List<TransactionEntryEntity> createCriteriaQuery(String cardHolderId, String accountId, int pageNumber,
        int pageSize, Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<TransactionEntryEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(TransactionEntryEntity.class);
    // Root<CardHolderEntity> cardHolder = cq.from(CardHolderEntity.class);
    Root<TransactionEntryEntity> transactionEntry = cq.from(TransactionEntryEntity.class);

    Join<TransactionEntryEntity, TransactionEntity> transaction = transactionEntry
            .join(TransactionEntryEntity_.transactionEntity);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    // Default Predicates for transactions
    predicates
            .add(cb.equal(transactionEntry.get(TransactionEntryEntity_.cardHolderEntity).get(CardHolderEntity_.id),
                    cardHolderId));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(transactionEntry.get(TransactionEntryEntity_.valid), 'Y'));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.retcode), "00"));

    // For Transaction API with acountId Path Variable
    if ((accountId != null) && (!accountId.trim().isEmpty())) {
        Join<TransactionEntryEntity, AccountEntity> account = transactionEntry
                .join(TransactionEntryEntity_.accountEntity);
        predicates.add(cb.equal(account.get(AccountEntity_.id), accountId));
    }
    if (!allRequestParams.isEmpty()) {
        String startDate = allRequestParams.get("minDate");
        String endDate = allRequestParams.get("maxDate");
        String merchantName = allRequestParams.get("merchantName");
        String date = allRequestParams.get("date");

        // Filter for Transactions with specific Date or with Start/End
        // date.
        if ((date != null) && !date.trim().isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.date), DateUtil.getSqlStartDate(date),
                    DateUtil.getSqlEndDate(date)));
        } else if ((startDate != null) && (!startDate.trim().isEmpty()) && (endDate != null)
                && (!endDate.trim().isEmpty())) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.date), DateUtil.getSqlStartDate(startDate),
                    DateUtil.getSqlEndDate(endDate)));
        } else if (((null == endDate) || (endDate.trim().isEmpty())) && (startDate != null)
                && (!startDate.trim().isEmpty())) {
            predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.date),
                    DateUtil.getSqlStartDate(startDate)));
        } else if (((null == startDate) || (startDate.trim().isEmpty())) && (endDate != null)
                && (!endDate.trim().isEmpty())) {
            predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.date),
                    DateUtil.getSqlEndDate(endDate)));
        }

        // Filter by merchant name
        if (((merchantName != null) && !merchantName.trim().isEmpty())) {
            Join<TransactionEntity, MerchantEntity> merchant = transaction.join(TransactionEntity_.merchantEntity);
            predicates.add(
                    cb.like(cb.lower(merchant.get(MerchantEntity_.name)), "%" + merchantName.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
    }

    cq.select(transactionEntry).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(transaction.get(TransactionEntity_.date)));
    TypedQuery<TransactionEntryEntity> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

    // For Paging of Transactions
    if ((pageNumber > 0) && (pageSize > 0)) {
        qry.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
        qry.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    }
    return qry.getResultList();
}
```